# How do I prevent my audio from cutting out when I open another program

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth

If I have spotify open and a song is playing, and then I open up a browser and go to youtube, for 3-5 seconds all audio from my computer will stop being played through my bluetooth speakers (anker soundcore 2 in stereo pairing mode).

Essentially if I interact with a window that plays audio, all audio from my computer stops being played for 3-5 seconds.

I'm using windows 10.

How do I stop the bluetooth speakers from cutting out every time I open a second program that could output audio?

*edit*

I just recorded the screen and audio, and when my audio cuts out from my speakers, the recording I did with OBS captures all of the audio. So whatever is going on is only preventing the audio from being played through the speakers, but I can still capture it with OBS

*edit2*

When I launch GTA 5, my audio cuts out for so long that I usually end up just turning my speakers off and then on again. When it cuts out when I launch GTA 5, the speaker makes the beep noise like it's just been connected for the first time.

I have a bluetooth headset, and I can have that connected for audio and this won't happen.

Comment: I don't believe that's the case. I'm currently using 8 gb of my 64 gb of ram. My CPU is a ryzen 9 3900x. I just recorded the screen and audio, and when my audio cuts out from my speakers, the recording I did with OBS captures all of the audio. So whatever is going on is only preventing the audio from being played through the speakers, but I can still capture it with OBS

Comment: You're correct. Knowing the machine specs may help get a better suggestion; that information can be added to your question.